# Setting Sinatra template options works locally, broken on Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, erb

My Sinatra web site uses an admittedly ghetto way of switching between two languages, which works perfectly on my local machine, but not on Heroku.

My `app.rb` is as follows:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/'  do
  set :erb, :views => settings.views + "/en"
  erb :index, :layout => false, :views => settings.views
end

get '/tr'  do
  set :erb, :views => settings.views + "/tr"
  redirect to('/home')
end
get '/en'  do
  set :erb, :views => settings.views + "/en"
  redirect to('/home')
end

get '/home'  do
  erb :home
end
get '/products' do
  erb :products
end
...
```

When I click on the links that go to the `/en` and `/tr` urls, I am correctly redirected to the `/home` link, but the views folder does not change.

My gems are the same versions in both environments:

```
rack (1.4.1)
rack-protection (1.2.0)
tilt (1.3.3)
sinatra (1.3.3)
bundler (1.3.2)
```

[Link to the site](http://www.reda-turkey.com/)

Help, please.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest replacing your admittedly ghetto way with something more robust like the i18n gem

[here is a tutorial](http://www.dafyddcrosby.com/using-i18n-in-sinatra.html)

And instead of using the browser's language (in example) you could do something like this in a before filter

```
before do
  case request.path_info
    when /^\/tr/ then set :locale, "tr"
    else set :locale, "en"
  end
end
```

and in helpers

```
helpers do
  def get_locale
    settings.locale
  end
  # other helpers from example
end
```

That way you only need one copy of your view templates, reducing the complication of changing all views when you only need to change one element (for example)

If you want to test your sinatra app like it will act on heroku you can throw on a `RACK_ENV=production` before starting your server. Ex. `RACK_ENV=production ruby my_app.rb`